# How does the _first_of_month (current_date) Cognos function work?

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

How does the _first_of_month (current_date) Cognos function work?

If the current date today is September 8, does it return all the value from September 1 to September 8? Month to date. Or does is return the value of the past month? Does it only return a value of 1 day?

So if I have a column CreatedDate then I use the function like this.

[CreatedDate]=_first_of_month (current_date)

This is an example of the CreatedDate column.

[image]

Comment: It will return the same year and month (in your example current_date) but the day is always set to 1.

Comment: So these are Month to Date values? Or Year to Date? Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately no, just a single date which the day part is set to 1. Do you need Month to Date values? you can set your condition to
[CreatedDate] >= _first_of_month (current_date) AND [CreatedDate] <= current_date instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

_first_of_month() takes a date value and returns a date value corresponding to the first day of the month of the value passed in.

Passing in: 2015-08-15 Returns: 2015-08-01

Passing in: 2014-03-21 Returns: 2014-03-01

Passing in: 1996-07-22 Returns: 1996-07-01

It's key to remember that the type of the return value will be another date.

Comment: So if the date today is September 9, I get records from Sept 1- Sept 9? Is that it? Or just September 1 records only? Thank you.

Comment: Just Septwmber 1. You pass in a single date and you get back a single date.